# Problems installing IJulia with Enthought Python

Tags: ipython, julia

I'm trying to install IJulia - to take advantage of the ipython integration

However, I get this error:

```julia
julia> Pkg.build("IJulia")
INFO: Building Homebrew
HEAD is now at 7dbece7 Merge branch 'kegpkg' of github.com:staticfloat/homebrew into kegpkg
HEAD is now at e7a2203 Tab fix didn't work, revert to old behavior
INFO: Building Nettle
INFO: Building ZMQ
INFO: Building IJulia
=======================================================================[ ERROR: IJulia ]=======================================================================

IPython is required for IJulia, got errors
   ErrorException("invalid version string: 1.0.dev")
   could not start process `ipython2 --version`: no such file or directory (ENOENT)
   could not start process `ipython3 --version`: no such file or directory (ENOENT)
at /Users/bdhammel/.julia/IJulia/deps/build.jl:17

===============================================================================================================================================================

=======================================================================[ BUILD ERRORS ]========================================================================

WARNING: IJulia had build errors.

 - packages with build errors remain installed in /Users/bdhammel/.julia
 - build a package and all its dependencies with `Pkg.build(pkg)`
 - build a single package by running its `deps/build.jl` script

===============================================================================================================================================================
```

I have ipython installed though:

```
$ which ipython
/Users/bdhammel/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/ipython
```

So I'm not sure what it's complaining about

Comment: It seems to complain about version compatibility. What does `ipython --version` print?

Comment: That was the problem! `ipython` was version 1.0.dev. I tried using canopy's built in Package manager, but it would crash on the install. `pip install ipython --upgrade` seemed to work fine - upgraded to version 1.1.0. Please submit an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution might be to update your Canopy install, I think it has an auto-updater. Barring that, please post output ivarne asked for, and also post:

```
julia> convert(VersionNumber, chomp(readall(`ipython --version`))
```

1.0-dev should be supported, but maybe the version string from Canopy version looks different than what IJulia is expecting.